# BadInputFilter No Longer Works

Tags: tomcat

The book Tomcat: The Definitive Guide (2nd Edition), O'Reilly, Jason Brittain provides a Tomcat filter (and a valve) to filter out bad user input from HTTP requests to help avoid malicious attacks.  I have used the filter for years, and I found it to be a great security tool for web applications running on Tomcat.  It used to work with older versions of Tomcat, but with more recent versions of Tomcat, it no longer works.  What's worse is that if fails silently.  You have to learn through experimentation that it doesn't work.

It appears that the filter is editing a copy of the request parameters, but the actual request parameters are not changed when the request gets to the web server.  I tried the valve, but it also fails to work in the same way.  You can use the filter or valve to block HTTP requests that have bad data in the parameters, but you can no longer use it to edit the parameters.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?  That is, does there exist a version of BadInputFilter or a substitute for it that will actually modify the request parameters and then send the modified parameters to the web server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was unable to find a good answer for this question, so I developed my own answer and published it in a detailed article on JavaWorld.  See [BadInputFilter revisited](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-11-2013/131114-badinputfilter-revisited.html) for the answer to this question.

Comment: Would it be possible to summarize the relevant portions of that article in your answer, to protect against potential link rot and to prevent users from having to click through to get the core message?

Comment: Brief Summary:

HttpServletRequest has a method named getParameterMap() that returns an immutable Map that maps parameter names to values. In order to "escape" user input, you need to be able to modify these parameter names and/or values. You can't modify the Map directly, but you can wrap the the entire HttpServletRequest in an HttpServletRequestWrapper, which can then passed along to the destination resource in place of the original request. The “wrapped” request copies and escapes the original parameter names and values, and these are the ones that the destination resource has access to.